# Efficiency of Peltier cell vs driving topology

Tags: peltier

I have a problem with a Peltier cell, I use the same Peltier cell in two different applications, in one it is powered via an H bridge like this:
[image]
while in the other application, since it only needs to cool, it is powered by a simple MOS like this:
[image]
The problem is that under the same conditions, I see that through the H bridge the efficiency of the Peltier cell is much greater, in other words to move the same amount of heat, feed with the H bridge it consumes much less current than the solution with the only mosfets.

At this point I have some questions: Is this situation normal? Also from a theoretical point of view is what I see correct?

From what I understand, the H bridge competes with a buck regulator, so in the first case the TEC is powered with constant current, while in the second case is powered with an impulsive current, the difference comes from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, the H bridge competes with a buck regulator, so in the first case the TEC is powered with constant current, while in the second case is powered with an impulsive current, the difference comes from there?

Assuming the filter components after the H bridge are sufficient at your PWM frequency to give you a reasonably constant current, yes.

The amount a heat a TEC moves is proportional to current. The amount waste heat it generates is proportional to current **squared**, or the RMS current. TECs tend to be used very inefficiently where the waste heat dominates their performance.

Consider a 50% PWM waveform of 2 A for example. The mean current is 1 A. However, the RMS current is 1.414 A. The PWM waveform shifts exactly the same amount of heat as a steady 1 A, but has twice the heating power.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a N-MOSFET for your high side switch, that means you need a gate voltage of at least the vgs threshold + VBRG to fully open the MOSFET and in practise you want somewhat more than that, datasheet tells you what's the gate voltage for rated current.

If gate voltage = VBRG, then the voltage drop over the MOSFET is approximately same as threshold voltage.

Presuming the gate voltage is not > VBRG, use a p-fet which will not have, as long as VBRG is > threshold voltage of the p-fet.